# What's the proper way to include inlined javascript-source?

Tags: themes, javascript, theme-options

I'm making a theme where I'm including a javascript-lib which wants to be loaded/instrumented with a potion of generated code at `document.ready()`-time. Generated because some theme-options are influencing the behaviour.

I properly load the `.js` of the lib with `wp_enqueue_script()`. Now I need a proper way to put the the javascript-code below the script.

I found a way which suggests to change `header.php` to include the code after the call to `wp_head()`.

I think my question is, is there a way to add js-code so that the call to `wp_head()` includes at in the right place? Is there a `wp_enqueue_script_code()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To print JavaScript code to your page, you have several paths to choose from. The most obvious would be the [`wp_footer`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer) action. Just hook a function to it and make it print your JavaScript/jQuery code, wrapped in `<script />` tags.

**// EDIT**
As an addition, if your custom JavaScript/jquery code is static (i.e., there are no dynamic parts in it), you should put it in a separate JS file and enqueue it with the lib as dependency. But you explicitly asked for printing so that's what I answered.

As for your comment, as long as your code doesn't have to be executed before the page has been rendered—which doesn't seem to be the case, according to your question (`document.ready`)—this is just best practice to enqueue script files in the footer.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. So, the same way I could hook an action to `wp_head()`, couldn't I? If not, why is `wp_footer()` better suitable?

Comment: Yes you can do the same with `wp_head` action. But footer is always recommended for scripts unless you need your scripts in header for some specific purpose.